# libusb_hotplug_register_callback does not accept my callback function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compilation, libusb-1.0

I am developing an app to detect when an USB is plugged in and out in vc++ with visual studio 2012. I have added the libusb 1.0 library which it is a cross platform library right now.

I have a problem of compilation with the callback function while I try to register the event handler.

```
#include "detect_usb_libusb.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libusb.h>


static int count = 0;    

int hotplug_callback(struct libusb_context *ctx, struct libusb_device *dev,
                                                libusb_hotplug_event event, void *user_data) {
        static libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int rc;
        (void)libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
        if (LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED == event) {
            rc = libusb_open(dev, &handle);
            if (LIBUSB_SUCCESS != rc) {
                printf("Could not open USB device\n");
            }
        } else if (LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT == event) {
            if (handle) {
                libusb_close(handle);
                handle = NULL;
            }
        } else {
                printf("Unhandled event %d\n", event);
        }
        count++;
  return 0;
}

int main (void) {
  libusb_hotplug_callback_handle handle;
  int rc;
  libusb_init(NULL);

  rc = libusb_hotplug_register_callback(  NULL, (libusb_hotplug_event) (LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED |
                                            LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT), LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_ENUMERATE,
                                            0x2047, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY,
                                            LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY, hotplug_callback, NULL,
                                            &handle);  

  if (LIBUSB_SUCCESS != rc) {
    printf("Error creating a hotplug callback\n");
    libusb_exit(NULL);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  while (count < 2) {
    _sleep(10000);
  }
  libusb_hotplug_deregister_callback(NULL, handle);
  libusb_exit(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

I got this code from the libusb API and I am really lost at this point. The exception says:

```
 error C2664: 'libusb_hotplug_register_callback' : cannot convert parameter 7 from 'int (__cdecl *)(libusb_context *,libusb_device *,libusb_hotplug_event,void *)' to 'libusb_hotplug_callback_fn'
```

But I don't know how converting my "int (__cdecl *)" function to a "int( * libusb_hotplug_callback_fn)"

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is the way: `static int LIBUSB_CALL hotplug_callback(libusb_context *ctx, libusb_device *dev, libusb_hotplug_event event, void *user_data)` source: https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/examples/hotplugtest.c

Answer (score 0):

I had same error on VS 2013, in libusb_hotplug_register_callback() just change

```
hotplug_callback
```

to

```
(libusb_hotplug_callback_fn) hotplug_callback
```

Answer (score -1):

This is most probably due to

```
 rc = libusb_hotplug_register_callback(  NULL, (libusb_hotplug_event) (**LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED |LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_LEFT**), LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_ENUMERATE,0x2047, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY,                                LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY, hotplug_callback, NULL,&handle);
```

Try using

```
rc = libusb_hotplug_register_callback(  NULL, (libusb_hotplug_event) (LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED), LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_ENUMERATE,0x2047, LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY,                                LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_MATCH_ANY, hotplug_callback, NULL,&handle);
```

It is because due to or (`|`) operator it is converting to integer after bitwise OR operation.